# I have an array of objects with an order and I have to merge it with another array that contains other information. Which is the fastest algorithm?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I have **two arrays** of objects that describe stops of a bus line:

1. `array1` contains objects which have a **stopId** and **time** (i.e. 12.00). The same stopId *can be repeated* more than once with different time.
2. `array2` contains objects which have a **stopId** and a **stopName**. StopIds are the same as array1 but they *are not repeated*.

How can I get a new array that **has the same order** as `array1`. But that also contains the name of the stops (`stopName`)? I need **the fastest algorithm** possible.

### Here is an example:

```
array1 = [{ stopId : 2845, time : "12:00"},
          { stopId : 2900, time : "12:02"},
          { stopId : 2901, time : "12:05"}, 
          ...
          { stopId : 2845, time : "12:25"}] 

array2 = [{ stopId : 2845, stopName: "NewYork"},
          { stopId : 2901, stopName: "London"},
          { stopId : 2900, stopName: "Rome"}, 
          ...]

result = [{ stopId : 2845, time : "12:00", stopName: "NewYork"},
          { stopId : 2900, time : "12:02", stopName: "Rome"},
          { stopId : 2901, time : "12:05", stopName: "London"}, 
          ...
          { stopId : 2845, time : "12:25", stopName: "NewYork"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a good use case for .map()

```
const result = array1.map((val) => {
  stop = array2.filter(val2 => val2.stopId === val.stopId)
    if (stop[0] && stop[0].stopName) {
      val.stopName = stop[0].stopName
      }
    return val;
  })
```

If you find another method, you can time with console.time() and console.timeEnd() to easily test speed :)

Comment: PS. Here is some documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map You may also want to check .reduce() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce as it could offer solutions too.